# Mysql : The syntax '--log-slow-queries' is deprecated and will be removed in a fu$

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have just changed my mysql settings to use innodb but i keep getting this warning in the msqld.log

'The syntax '--log-slow-queries' is deprecated and will be removed in a fu$'

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By default, the slow query log is disabled. To specify the initial
>   slow query log state explicitly, use --slow_query_log[={0|1}]. With no
>   argument or an argument of 1, --slow_query_log enables the log. With
>   an argument of 0, this option disables the log. To specify a log file
>   name, use --slow_query_log_file=file_name. To specify the log
>   destination, use --log-output (as described in Section 5.2.1,
>   “Selecting General Query and Slow Query Log Output Destinations”). The
>   older option to enable the slow query log file, --log-slow-queries, is
>   deprecated.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/slow-query-log.html